# Is there a supermassive black hole in the center of every single galaxy?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, galaxies

I've read that there's a supermassive black hole in the center of every single galaxy, as we confirmed theres for example one in the center of ours, and in the andromeda galaxy, but does that confirm theres one in every single galaxy? And if so, why? Was it born at the beginning of the galaxys birth?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The fact that we have a supermassive black hole at the center of our galaxy of course is not sufficient in order to state that there is one black hole in every single galaxy out there. You could never have a conclusive and certain confirmation unless you're able to identify all black holes and all galaxies present in the universe, which is not so easy to do.

Nevertheless, astronomers do believe that supermassive black holes lie at the center of all large galaxies, as in our own Milky Way. If we focus for example on stellar black holes, they are very difficult to detect and judging from the number of stars large enough to produce them, scientists have estimated that there are as many as ten million to a billion in the Milky Way alone. This could be interpreted as a strong suggestion that every galaxy has at the center a black hole, but it's not a conclusive proof.

Another possible explanation of this hypothesis relies on the fact that one possible mechanism (not the only one of course) for the formation of supermassive black holes involves a chain reaction of collisions of stars in compact star clusters that results in extremely massive stars, which then collapse to form intermediate-mass black holes. The star clusters then sink to the center of the galaxy, where the intermediate-mass black holes merge to form a supermassive black hole.

Comment: I am curious: does the last bit imply there is a star cluster surrounding each galactic black hole, or what?

Comment: Again, it's impossible to know if it's true for each galactic black hole, but according to the experience we gained with the Hubble Space Telescope observations, if we go deep inside a star system of any size, it's quite safe to expect a black hole. This is at least reasonable for midsize black holes which are located at the hearts of globular clusters. For the other sizes I'm not expert enough in the subject.

Comment: Sure, what I was asking though was not whether a black hole was present, but whether if, _where_ such a black hole is present, there is _also_ something like a globular cluster around it (at least in most cases). I.e. in the center of a decent galaxy like Milky Way or Andromeda, is there a giant globular cluster (but much smaller than the galactic-core "bulge" as a whole) surrounding the central black hole? Or is it just floating amongst stars with density similar to the rest of the core?

Comment: I think it's quite safe to assume it. If I'm not wrong in both the Milky Way and Andromeda galaxies there's something similar to what you said. My opinion is that the same applies also for the other large galaxies out there.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer There are dense star clusters ("nuclear star clusters"; NSCs) at the centers of most *disk* galaxies, including the MW and Andromeda, which surround their black holes. These are often similar in size to -- though usually more massive than -- globular clusters. However, most really massive elliptical galaxies do *not* have identifiable NSCs.

Answer (score 6):

Brief answer until someone with more knowledge adds details.

The answer is about evidence, theoretical models of galaxy formation, and the balance of probability. As I understand it, the evidence and knowledge acquired to date is such that it would be reasonable to hold that most galaxies have a black hole at their centre. I would not go so far as to say "every" but I am not ruling that out as a possibility.

The evidence includes the observations of, and models of, quasars. We can't really claim to know for sure what quasars are, but processes associated with black holes seem to be the only viable candidate.

Comment: The black hole at our galaxy's center is not a very conspicuous object. Similar objects in other galaxies are difficult/impossible to detect. Thus, the empirical evidence is a bit thin here.

Comment: Galaxies may lose their SMBH due to collision. That's suspected for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abell_2261 and it looks like it's currently happening with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CID-42

Answer (score 3):

Observational evidences indicate that almost every large galaxy has a supermassive black hole at its center.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermassive_black_hole

Can we safely say that every galaxy has a black hole at its center?
No

Can we safely say that almost every galaxy has a black hole at its center?
Yes

Comment: I think the evidence is not quite correctly stated in this answer. We have reasonably direct evidence in the case of about 10 non-quasar galaxies, and it's a good bet that quasars have black holes. From there it is a more a question of reasonable belief based on models of galaxy formation.

Comment: @AndrewSteane We have "reasonably direct" evidence in the case of something more than 100 "non-quasar" galaxies. (A somewhat out-of-date listing: [Saglia et al. 2016](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016ApJ...818...47S))

Comment: @PeterErwin thanks for the information. My comment was motivated partly by the long careful history of building up evidence for even the most compelling cases. Having looked at Saglia et al I think they are ready to say "black hole" and then get on with establishing correlations with bulge etc. The evidence that it really is a black hole is partly resting on the few cases where the most thorough observation is possible. If those were in doubt then so would the others be.

Comment: @AndrewSteane Well, as a coauthor of the Saglia et al. paper, I can state that we were not that cavalier about black hole detections ;-). Section 2.1 discusses cases where we did not include what we considered to be uncertain measurements.

In any case, the "100 plus" galaxies I am suggesting are direct dynamical measurements of massive, compact central dark objects in galaxy centers, not "belief based on models of galaxy formation".

Comment: @PeterErwin Suppose we wanted to press you on this, we would acknowledge that there is a lot of mass within some volume which the measurements can resolve, but then we will ask whether it could possibly be a million solar-mass-sized lumps of matter, or something like that, rather then a black hole. I think the million lumps are ruled out by arguing that such a cloud would not be stable for the long periods involved. That's what I had in mind with "models of galaxy formation". If I am on wrong on this then happy to be corrected.

Comment: @PeterErwin ... however I am glad to have these 100-odd examples added to this answer; they certainly make the case very strong.

Comment: @AndrewSteane There were a number of studies done (back in the 1990s, I think) that demonstrated that large numbers of stellar-mass objects in a small space would indeed either collapse (to make a BH) or disperse within a few million or tens of millions of years. For me, that's not in the regime of "galaxy formation", because it doesn't matter how such a collection of objects might form in the first place (that would be "models of galaxy formation"); it's the local dynamics that make it unstable.

Comment: @PeterErwin you are quite right! I was imprecise in my use of language at that point in my comment.

Answer (score 3):

At least, it's a good guess that **spiral** galaxies should have a black hole in the core, according to [a correlation noticed](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/789/2/124) between spiral arms pitch angle and black hole mass located in the spiral galaxy core,- from the research of 140 local volume-limited spiral galaxies sample:

$$ M_{_{SMBH}} \propto 10^{-0.062~~|~P~|} ,$$

where $P$ is spiral arms pitch angle.

Of course correlation was extracted from a local spiral galaxies,- not all of spiral galaxies in a visible universe. But again, many laws were extrapolated using observational data available at hand (Hubble law also was not produced from all galaxies redshift in the universe). It's impossible to observe everything and in every time moment.

Anyway it's a good guess that each spiral galaxy should have a black hole in the center, less or more massive.
Other types of galaxies are less likely having black holes in the center, due to the fact that they are too small or of irregular shape, not rotating, etc.

Comment: Strictly I think the logic is that one can establish the correlation between pitch angle and some sort of mass M at the core, but this correlation does not establish that that mass is owing to a black hole. Having said that, the suggestion that M or a large fraction of it is a black hole is quite reasonable in view of the evidence of our galaxy and various other evidence.

Comment: ... but I'm glad someone mentioned this correlation because I was aware of it as a good thing to mention but I didn't have it to hand when I wrote my brief answer.

Comment: Citation from above mentioned article if you are too lazy to read it : _Strong evidence suggests that **supermassive black holes** (SMBHs) reside in the nuclei of most galaxies and that correlations exist between the mass of the SMBH and certain properties of the host galaxy (Kormendy & Richstone 1995; Kormendy & Gebhardt 2001)._

Comment: I read that and also Berrier et al 2013, cited therein, who state: "Direct determination of SMBH mass depends on instrumentation which can observe the motion of stars, gas, and dust in the immediate vicinity of the black hole". This is possible for some local galaxies. But the situation remains as I said in my first comment. One does not know the central mass is a black hole (as opposed to, say, millions of black dwarfs), only that this is a good bet because of other evidence such as quasars, observations in Milky Way, and models of galaxy evolution. ...

Comment: So the correlation is not evidence of SMBH; rather the assumption of SMBH (which is based on other evidence) allows the correlation to be established.

Comment: The (nearby) spiral galaxy M33 has no SMBH (https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0107135; the upper limit is only 1500 solar masses, well below even the most generous definition of "supermassive").

Comment: The cited paper references earlier studies (by the same group) which amount to "in those spiral galaxies where a SMBH has been measured, we find a loose correlation between pitch angle and SMBH mass." (They mostly ignore galaxies like M33 that don't agree with this.) So, no, one cannot  argue that "every spiral galaxy must have a black hole in the core".

Comment: Agree, my argument was too harsh, I've changed it to a bit more constructive.